# "Your file was not found" error appears when I click a button in an HTML form

Tags: javascript, html, forms, button

I am new to HTML and javascript.

I am writing a basic form that (for now) is supposed to take the names of "male staff members" and "female staff members" entered by the user, and show a list of each once a button is pressed. Initially, the button seemed to be working, and a list of both male and female staff members was displayed beneath the form. I'm not sure what I did to change this, but now when I press the button, I get an error page with "your file was not found."

Here is the HTML form that contains the button:

```
    <form method="post" action="new_ele2.php" id = "form1">

        <!--text button to add new row for a male name (calls the add_new function)-->
        <p id="addnew">
            <a href="javascript:add_feed(1)">Add New Male Name</a>
        </p>

        <!--table for male staff names-->
        <table>
        <tr>
            <td valign=top> Enter male staff names (click 'add new' for each new name):</td>
            <td valign=top>
                <div id="newName1">
                <div class="maleNames">
                    <input type="text" name="feedName[]" value="" size="50">
                </div>
                </div>
             </td>
        </tr>
        </table>

        <br>

        <!--text button to add new row for a female name-->
        <p id="addnew1">
            <a href="javascript:add_feed(2)">Add New Female Name</a>
        </p>

        <!--table for female staff names-->
        <table>
        <tr>
            <td valign=top> Enter female staff names (click 'add new' for each new name):</td>
            <td valign=top>
                <div id="newName3">
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </table>

        <p>
            <button onclick="validate(this)">Submit names</button>
        </p>
        <p id="testing"> </p>
        <p id="testing1"> </p>
    </form>
```

And here is the javascript "validate" function being called by the button:

```
function validate(frm) {
    var ele = frm.elements['feedName[]'];
    var eleList = [];
    if (! ele.length) {
        //alert(ele.value);
    }
    for(var i=0; i<ele.length; i++) {
        eleList[i] = ele[i].value;
    }

    var ele1 = frm.elements['feedName1[]'];
    var eleList1 = [];
    if (! ele1.length) {
        //alert(ele.value);
    }
    for(var j=0; j<ele1.length; j++) {
        eleList1[j] = ele1[j].value;
    }
    document.getElementById("testing").innerHTML = eleList;
    document.getElementById("testing1").innerHTML = eleList1;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: You have `<form method="post" action="new_ele2.php"...` do you have a `new_ele2.php` file to handle the form submission? If not, then this is why you're getting a 404.

Comment: Please confirm the php file exists and is saved in the correct directory